# list of event handelers

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I want to create a dictionary  of event handlers , or something like dictionary of method with key

and use it in method that accept key , when this function be called I search using the key and fire the event or the method

any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of `EventHandler`:

```
Dictionary<string, EventHandler> eventHandlers   // using a string or whatever you like for a key
```

And invoke like so:

```
eventHandlers[key].Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's documented on MSDN: [How to: Use a Dictionary to Store Event Instances (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z4ka55h8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).